# inner join on a left join not returning record when the left joined record is not present

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, left-join, inner-join

```
|----------------------------|
|  Tbl_1                     |
|--------------|-------------|
|  id          |  name_1     |
|--------------|-------------|
|  1           |  t_1_rec_1  |
|--------------|-------------|

|------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Tbl_2                                                     |
|-------|--------------|-----------|------------|------------|
|  id   |  name_2      | tbl_1_id  |  tbl_3_id  |  tbl_4_id  |
|-------|--------------|-----------|------------|------------|
|  1    | t_2_rec_1    | 1         | 1          |  2         |
|  2    | t_2_rec_2    | 1         | 2          |  1         |
|-------|--------------|-----------|------------|------------|

|------------------------|
|  Tbl_3                 |
|----------|-------------|
|  id      |  name_3     |
|----------|-------------|
|  1       |  t_3_rec_1  |
|  2       |  t_3_rec_2  |
|----------|-------------|

|----------------------|
|  Tbl_4               |
|--------|-------------|
|  id    |  name_4     |
|--------|-------------|
|  1     |  t_4_rec_1  |
|  2     |  t_4_rec_2  |
|--------|-------------|


|--------------------------------------------|
| Tbl_5                                      |
|------|------------|------------|-----------|
|  id  |  name_5    |  tbl_2_id  | tbl_6_id  |
|------|------------|------------|-----------|
|  1   | t_5_rec_1  |  1         | 1         |
|  2   | t_5_rec_2  |  1         | 2         |
|------|------------|------------|-----------|

|----------------------------------|
|  Tbl_6                           |
|-------|------------|
|  id   | name_6     |
|-------|------------|
|  1    | t_6_rec_1  |
|  2    | t_6_rec_2  |
|-------|------------|
```

I am expecting these results:

```
t1.name_1  t2.name_2  t3.name_3  t4.name_4  t5.name_5   t6.name_6

t_1_rec_1  t_2_rec_1  t_3_rec_1  t_4_rec_2  t_5_rec_1   t_6_rec_1
t_1_rec_1  t_2_rec_1  t_3_rec_1  t_4_rec_2  t_5_rec_2   t_6_rec_2
t_1_rec_1  t_2_rec_2  t_3_rec_2  t_4_rec_1

select t1.name_1, t2.name_2, t3.name_3, t4.name_4, t5.name_5, t6.name_6
from Tbl_1 as t1
left join Tbl_2 as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
inner join Tbl_3 as t3 on t2.tbl_3_id = t3.id
inner join Tbl_4 as t4 on t2.tbl_4_id = t4.id
left join Tbl_5 as t5 on t5.id = t2.id
inner join Tbl_6 as t6 on t2.tbl_6_id = t6.id
```

But this does not work!!!!! The third row is not returned. Changing the last inner join (Tbl_6) to a left join does produce the third row.

I understand that the inner join between Tbl_5 and Tbl_6 would  result in no Tbl_5 record but I would expect that the left join between Tbl_2 and Tbl_5 would result in Tbl_2 and its inner joined Tbl_3 and Tbl_4 records to be there and as a result of the Tbl_1 left join to Tbl_2 that I would get the third row.

What am I missing? (I would rather not have to change the inner join because I do not want Tbl_5 records that do not have a Tbl_6 entry latter on down the road ) Also, this query is generated from a Zend Db class and I would need to be able to incorporate any answer into that but I suppose if there is a query that works properly, or as I expect it to, then I will figure out how to get Zend to produce it...

Comment: Process the tables in order 1,2,5,3,4,6 in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL (and MySQL), the `inner join`, `left outer join`, `right outer join`, and `cross join` operations all have the same precedence.  So, `a left join b inner join c` is `(a left join b) inner join  c`.  In the same way, the arithmetic expression `1 - 2 + 3` is `(1 - 2) + 3` and not `1 - (2 + 3)`.

With this in mind, let's look at your `from` clause:

```
from Tbl_1 as t1
left join Tbl_2 as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
inner join Tbl_3 as t3 on t2.tbl_3_id = t3.id
inner join Tbl_4 as t4 on t2.tbl_4_id = t4.id
left join Tbl_5 as t5 on t5.id = t2.id
inner join Tbl_6 as t6 on t2.tbl_6_id = t6.id
```

The first inner join is `t2.tbl_3_id = t3.id`.  The column `t2.tbl_3_id` will be NULL if there is no match from `t1` on the `t2` table.  Because `NULL` values don't match, the effect is to turn the first join into an inner join.

You can fix this with syntax such as:

```
inner join Tbl_3 as t3 on t2.tbl_3_id = t3.id or t2.id is null
```

(The NULL comparison is to `t2.id` rather than `t2.tbl_3_id` just in case that id could be NULL in a valid match.)

You can continue this logic for the subsequent joins.

The mixing of outer joins and inner joins does *not* automatically convert the outer joins to inner joins.  That depends on the conditions in the `on` clause.

Personally, I find following the semantics of joins to be rather cumbersome.  I write almost all my queries using only inner joins or only left outer joins.  That is, either I keep rows where everything matches or I keep all the rows in the first table.

If I want to mix join types, then then I have two options.  The first is to use subqueries -- which, in MySQL, can result in performance problems.  Or, I use `left outer join`s and add conditions in a `where` clause to effect the logic I want.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Regarding to your first line (`In SQL (and MySQL)...`), I don't have the material to try right now but I think Oracle behaves differently.

Comment: I have tried this " or t2.id is null" and that resulted in a returned record for all of the records in Tbl_3 (actually Tbl_6 in mycase, but the point being that checking the parent id for null on the inner join only treated all the possibilities for a child match as true. I am likely going to have to just make them all left joins since further thought on this has lead me to decide that I probbly want to see where a child is missing. If this observation that all child records are being returned makes you think of something else that might work, I would appreciate hearing about it.